# Doxygen with page statistics

Tags: html, web, doxygen

I created a web-site using Doxygen on GitHub.io, and added a visitor counter.
It works fine, except that I need to edit my index.html
when I upload a new version. Is there some trick to insert the needed code directly
in the .dox file, so that it will be inserted in the index.html file?

Comment: Not sure what you want as is is abstract what you are writing. Please give an example of what you have / want to change, so mainly a small doxygen project showing what you mean. Furthermore which version of doxygen?

Comment: The comment looks like been broken and also it is still unclear. You should add some code into your original  question showing the HTML you would like. I think you should have a look at the possibilities of `\htmlonly` (assuming the requested code should only land in the body of the index page).